# Regular expression for 1-199 (including both 1 and 199) without Leading zeros

Tags: regex

Regular expression to match any number from 1 to 199. Leading zeros not be included, which means that f.ex. 015 is not allowed.

First, I know it may be better to convert it into integer or something, which I can check its range. But right now I am paly with ragular expresison.

Second, this it my first attemp.

```
^[1]?[1-9][0-9]?$
```

But it seems to miss the match of "10X" like 101, 102
Then I make another one:

```
^([1]\d{2} | [1-9][0-9]?)$
```

No sure this works. If not, what's wrong, otherwise, is there another elegant way(more generic) to write it, which can address problem like 1 ~ 1999 ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2})$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wA1bE5/1)

Comment: Looks the same to the second solution that I wrote.  I am wondering is there a more elegant way, which can solve problem like 1-1999 without much modification. Anyway, I will go with this one.

Answer (score -1):

The expression is: `^(1?\d{0,2})$`

Comment: This one don't looks correct to me.  It will also match pattern like, 1100

Comment: Your right, i retracted back to my old answer, but it accepts "03", "08"... and so on